# How to parse LinkedHashMap in moshi (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I am trying to create a JSON adapter for the following json

```
{
    "message": {
        "affenpinscher": [],
        "african": [],
        "airedale": [],
        "akita": [],
        "appenzeller": [],
        "australian": [
            "shepherd"
        ]
    },
    "status": "success"
}
```

I have tried the following

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class BreedList(
    val message: HashMap<String,List<String>> = HashMap<String,List<String>>()
)
```

and

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class BreedList(
    val message: Breed
)
```

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Breed(
    val breed: List<String>
)
```

But both scenarios give me the errors, is there a way to parse the following object, I need the key as well as the list from the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a custom adapter.

To parse the JSON you posted:

```
data class Base (

    @field:Json(name = "message")
    val message : Message,

    @field:Json(name = "status")
    val status : String
```

)

```
data class Message (

    @field:Json(name = "affenpinscher")
    val affenpinscher : List<String>,

    @field:Json(name = "african") 
    val african : List<String>,

    @field:Json(name = "airedale")
    val airedale : List<String>,

    @field:Json(name = "akita")
    val akita : List<String>,

    @field:Json(name = "appenzeller") 
    val appenzeller : List<String>,

    @field:Json(name = "australian")
    val australian : List<String>
```

)

**Note**: instead of **String** you can use whatever data type you need or create custom classes like **Message**.